# Reading PKCS7 and .p12 file certificate information(subjectDN,vaildstartfrom,ValildTo..) through java

Tags: certificate, pkcs#7, java-security

I am trying to implement Digital certificate validity utility using java. I can able to read the certification information(subjectDN, Issure info, validitity..etc) if the certificate in .cert,.cer but can't able to read certificate information from .p7b and .p12 certificate format. I have used the BouncyCastle security provider to read .p7b and .p12 certificate content but not able to get with that security provider might be i was missing on this. I am referring online resources  to get some idea on this but not get guideline for this.Could you please someone give suggestion on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest if you're looking for validity of the certificate from p12, it can be done as below :

```
try {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream("pathToYourP12");
        keyStore.load(input, "password");
        certFromKeyStore = (X509Certificate)keyStore.getCertificate("keyStoreAllias");
        certFromKeyStore.checkValidity();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
// catch exception like if no valid p12 existing at the location, invalid password, or any other exception should get catch properly.
}
```